# TypeScript: Infer Key Value Type Without Discriminated Union

Tags: typescript

I'd like to use a type map to ensure that the type of an object's value for a specific key is known based on the value of of another key. For example:

```
type CurrencyValue = {
  code: string;
  value: number;
};

type FieldMap = {
  text: string;
  currency: CurrencyValue;
};

type FieldKind = keyof FieldMap;

type Field<T extends FieldType> = {
  kind: FieldKind;
  value: FieldMap[T];
};
```

In this example if I create an object of the shape `Field` if the value of its `kind` is "text" then it expects the type of `value` to be a `string`. Likewise, if the `kind` is "currency" then the `value` should be an object that matches the `CurrencyValue` type.

I can *almost* get this to work with the above setup but I need to add a parameter to the type:

```
// this works
const field: Field<"currency"> = {
  type: "currency",
  value: {
    code: "USD",
    value: 12,
  },
};

// this doesn't
// error: Generic type 'Field' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
const field: Field = {
  type: "currency",
  value: {
    code: "USD",
    value: 12,
  },
};
```

However, I don't want to have to specify the type parameter for these situations. Is there a way for TS to infer the `value` type without being specifically told so?

I am able to get this to work using discriminated unions:

```
type CurrencyField = {
    type: 'currency',
    value: CurrencyValue;
}

type TextField = {
    type: 'text',
    value: string;
}

type Field = CurrencyField | TextField;

const field: Field = {
    type: 'text',
    value: 'string'
}
```

but this isn't ideal as I would have to create several new types every time a new version of a `Field` is added. So, it would be preferable to be able to simply add them to the mapping.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You still need to create the discriminated union, but you can do this without manually writing it out:

```
type Field<T extends FieldKind = FieldKind> = T extends T ? {
  kind: T;
  value: FieldMap[T];
}: never;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgJwRAdgYxANQIYBs7QC8UA3gFBRRoD2AJhAFxQDOwCAligOYDcFUANzwEmKOAFsARhAR8AvnzKhIUAGLsIuWgFlsYKMXKVgEAB7AmrDtz6U0iZOhBN4SVBhz4I8xcujrNWgBpTloDKABrCBBqADM1DS1dMF9wf0TaAB4AFSgzExRaZgTAkMLwgK0y2gA+cNz81CKoXIB+Un4I0KZs20FhRhKkvQBtbIBdeVEIARlFAHp5qGoIshoUVihYjKZKsMNO7qgAIns3J2OAGn4hLyYjSio6QeOAVQBlABEr-kpbkSgAEYAEzXShya4KMhkRZQFArNbUDbALYZYG7DLhB5dQpMU4OdwgH5-AZ4n5QmFLBHrTbbQIAZgxgSxh1xJxM5mJ-TuJ3JfCAA)

This uses the distributive property of conditional types to generate from a union of fields names (such  as `"currency"|"text"`) a union of object types, one for each constituent of the original union ( `{ kind: "currency"; value: FieldMap["currency"]; } | { kind: "text"; value: FieldMap["text"]; }`

Comment: Thank you! This definitely works. Could you explain the `T extends T` conditional? I assume that the first `T` is distributed to the union of checking `"currency" extends T` and `"text" extends T`. In that case is the second `T` always the `kind` that is specified? Why does the first `T` in that case map over all of the possible types if we know what it's value is?

Comment: Conditional types distribute if the condition is over a naked type parameters. Such as `T`. So when TS sees `T extends T`, it will distribute whatever union is in `T` and apply the conditional type over each constituent `T extends T` will always be true, be don't really care about the condition. `T extends any` or `T extends unknown` would have also worked

Comment: Ahhh I understand - that makes total sense. Thank you for the clarification!